# pytest fails silently when can't instantiate PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication

Tags: python, unit-testing, runtime-error, pyqt5, pytest

When I run the following simple test

- with my installation of `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`, it passes.
- with my installation of `Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.` it fails silently, as detailed below. I can see it collecting the tests but do not get any indication it runs them, and it never announces a pass (or any result).

### My test code

```
"""Originally these imports were from tests for qutebrowser.utils.debug."""

import logging
import re
import time
import textwrap

import pytest
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt, QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyle, QFrame

from qutebrowser.utils import debug


def test_always_true(qapp, caplog):
    assert True == True
```

This is adapted from tests I was trying to run from the [qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/) project, specifically `tests\unit\utils\test_debug.py`. I will try to pare my own code down still further to a minimal case.

### What I see when pytest fails silently

```
C:\(path to qutebrowser)\qutebrowser>\python36\python.exe -bb -m pytest pjr\test_pjr.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
benchmark: 3.1.1 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
PyQt5 5.6 -- Qt runtime 5.6.2 -- Qt compiled 5.6.2
rootdir: C:\(path to qutebrowser)\qutebrowser, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: hypothesis-3.14.0, bdd-2.18.2, benchmark-3.1.1, catchlog-1.2.2, cov-2.5.1, faulthandler-1.3.1, instafail-0.3.0, mock-1.6.2, qt-2.1.2, repeat-0.4.1, rerunfailures-2.2, travis-fold-1.2.0, xvfb-1.0.0
collected 1 item s

pjr\test_pjr.py
```

### The underlying PyQt5 error

With help from @TheCompiler I found that `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets; app= QtWidgets.QApplication([])`

- runs fine in the Python instance used in the first (working) case above
- produces the following message in the instance used in the second (broken) case:

  ```
  This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
  in "".

  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
  ```

### Possibly useful trace

```
C:(path to qb)\qutebrowser>c:\python36\python.exe -bb -m pytest pjr\test_pjr.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
benchmark: 3.1.1 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
PyQt5 5.6 -- Qt runtime 5.6.2 -- Qt compiled 5.6.2
rootdir: C:(path to qb)\qutebrowser, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: hypothesis-3.14.0, bdd-2.18.2, benchmark-3.1.1, catchlog-1.2.2, cov-2.5.1, faulthandler-1.3.1, instafail-0.3.0, mock-1.6.2, qt-2.1.2, repeat-0.4.1, rerunfailures-2.2, travis-fold-1.2.0, xvfb-1.0.0
collecting 0 items
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB set_trace (IO-capturing turned off) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> c:(path to qb)\qutebrowser\pjr\test_pjr.py(36)<module>()
-> def test_always_true(qapp, caplog):
(Pdb) w
  c:\python36\lib\runpy.py(193)_run_module_as_main()
-> "__main__", mod_spec)
  c:\python36\lib\runpy.py(85)_run_code()
-> exec(code, run_globals)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pytest.py(73)<module>()
-> raise SystemExit(pytest.main())
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py(58)main()
-> return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(134)pytest_cmdline_main()
-> return wrap_session(config, _main)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(105)wrap_session()
-> session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(140)_main()
-> config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(150)pytest_collection()
-> return session.perform_collect()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(603)perform_collect()
-> items = self._perform_collect(args, genitems)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(640)_perform_collect()
-> self.items.extend(self.genitems(node))
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(779)genitems()
-> rep = collect_one_node(node)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(457)collect_one_node()
-> rep = ihook.pytest_make_collect_report(collector=collector)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(613)execute()
-> return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(248)_wrapped_call()
-> call_outcome = _CallOutcome(func)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(265)__init__()
-> self.result = func()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(329)pytest_make_collect_report()
-> 'collect')
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(157)__init__()
-> self.result = func()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(328)<lambda>()
-> lambda: list(collector.collect()),
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(401)collect()
-> self.session._fixturemanager.parsefactories(self)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py(1057)parsefactories()
-> holderobj = node_or_obj.obj
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(204)fget()
-> self._obj = obj = self._getobj()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(398)_getobj()
-> return self._importtestmodule()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(408)_importtestmodule()
-> mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py(662)pyimport()
-> __import__(modname)
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(961)_find_and_load()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(950)_find_and_load_unlocked()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(646)_load_unlocked()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(616)_load_backward_compatible()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py(211)load_module()
-> py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
> c:(path to qb)\qutebrowser\pjr\test_pjr.py(36)<module>()
-> def test_always_true(qapp, caplog):
(Pdb) w
  c:\python36\lib\runpy.py(193)_run_module_as_main()
-> "__main__", mod_spec)
  c:\python36\lib\runpy.py(85)_run_code()
-> exec(code, run_globals)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pytest.py(73)<module>()
-> raise SystemExit(pytest.main())
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py(58)main()
-> return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(134)pytest_cmdline_main()
-> return wrap_session(config, _main)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(105)wrap_session()
-> session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(140)_main()
-> config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(150)pytest_collection()
-> return session.perform_collect()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(603)perform_collect()
-> items = self._perform_collect(args, genitems)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(640)_perform_collect()
-> self.items.extend(self.genitems(node))
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py(779)genitems()
-> rep = collect_one_node(node)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(457)collect_one_node()
-> rep = ihook.pytest_make_collect_report(collector=collector)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(745)__call__()
-> return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(339)_hookexec()
-> return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(334)<lambda>()
-> _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(613)execute()
-> return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(248)_wrapped_call()
-> call_outcome = _CallOutcome(func)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(265)__init__()
-> self.result = func()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py(614)execute()
-> res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(329)pytest_make_collect_report()
-> 'collect')
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(157)__init__()
-> self.result = func()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py(328)<lambda>()
-> lambda: list(collector.collect()),
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(401)collect()
-> self.session._fixturemanager.parsefactories(self)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py(1057)parsefactories()
-> holderobj = node_or_obj.obj
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(204)fget()
-> self._obj = obj = self._getobj()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(398)_getobj()
-> return self._importtestmodule()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py(408)_importtestmodule()
-> mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py(662)pyimport()
-> __import__(modname)
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(961)_find_and_load()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(950)_find_and_load_unlocked()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(646)_load_unlocked()
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(616)_load_backward_compatible()
  c:\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py(211)load_module()
-> py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
> c:(path to qb)\qutebrowser\pjr\test_pjr.py(36)<module>()
-> def test_always_true(qapp, caplog):
(Pdb) c
collected 1 item

pjr\test_pjr.py
```